# Error 99999 All raster processes fail in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-calculator, slope, error-999999

I'm using ArcMap 10.8.1 and wanted to e.g. do a slope calculation on a Digital Elevation Model.

Now I´m getting `Error 999999` which usually refers to a bug or some unexpected error. First I thought it´s the one DEM but no other DEM raster works. So the program has a problem here. Hillshade also doesn´t work, gives `Error 010067`, Aspect `Error 99999`, Contour lines work.
Raster calculator gives the error "format GRID" whatever that means now.

It seems like all map algebra processes are buggy for me.

Should I reinstall or do something else?

---

I´ve reinstalled ArcGIS on this computer: No Changes.
I´ve installed in on a second computer: No Changes.

The Elevation models used mainly for testing for the error are:

```
srtm_lev_bnd21.tif
Cell size: 0,00029550817, 0,00029550817
1.66 GB
32 bit
GCS_WGS_1984

SRTM_30.tif
Cell size: 30,30151988, 30,30151987
1.4 GB
16bit
WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_36N

jor_utm.img
Cell size: 29,23080851, 29,23080851
98.91MB
16bit
WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_36N

dem_l8_5x5_high_clip.img
Cell size: 0,5, 0,5
3.33 GB
32 bit
UTM_Zone_36N
```

Comment: Please tell us about your input data.

Comment: Here is the detail for error for 010067:  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014968.  Maybe your non NoData values in the raster are causing problems for slope and aspect as well.

Comment: Sounds like it an issue with the source data. What projections are they set to? Are there any missing or null cell values? Where are the rasters stored? How are they named? All of these things could be a contributing factor to the tools failing. Can you provide these details by editting your question.

Comment: Hi Guys thank you very much for your answers: 

Stu: 
My input data are a number of DEMs, I´ve tried most I have available. 
These include ASTER, SRTM and Pleiades data. Different SRTM cuts as far as I recall. 
All have been processed by geographers and have worked beautifully in the past 6 years or so depending on age of the specific DEM.

GBG: 
Thank you very much, my geographer friend has just send me a fresh SRTM this morning and I´ve  tried Hillshade again with the same results. The DEM does not look like it contains no Data. The others worked previously.

Comment: Keagan: 
The larger SRTM and Aster are WGS84, the pleiades is UTM Zone 37N. 
Missing or no cell values I don´t know, how do I find out? 
Named: Differently, the latest one which failed is simply called SRTM-30m.tif 

I think I might have screwed up my installation of ArcGIS, I think I´ll give it a go with removing and reinstalling it as it by now entirely fails to do any of these things regardless of the input data. Shouldn´t happen, but maybe I´ve killed it...

Comment: check the full path to the files: make sure they are short names, with no space and no special characters. Some spatial analyst tools (and working with grids) remain very constraining.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the problem:
For some reason I get the error message when I just write a file name for the output files.
When I instead use the default gdb or manually write .tif to the filename it works.

What the hell...